# how to depoly the last modification on multi tenant database postgres without losing data

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I developed a website using spring boot in this application I'm using architecture multi tenant to manage my database.
The database on the host got filled with critical data and it still grows. Now I want to add new columns to different tables and also add new tables. The problem that I face, it is how to update the last modification on each schema without losing any data.

Ps: I'm using hibernate for creating new schema.

Ps : the new schema is created when a new user create a new account in the website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use Hibernate for that task.

The migrate the database Flyway or Liquibase should be used:

- https://flywaydb.org/
- https://www.liquibase.org/

Both libaries are very well integrated in Spring Boot as well:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-a-higher-level-database-migration-tool

Comment: i'm not using any of this libarires in the code , i'm using only hibernate

Comment: Yes and that's not recommended because it is very limited

Comment: obviously I can't update my database using hibernate, and I can't use liquibase because it's an old code, I think the only solution is to retrieve all schemas with the data  and i'm gonna  add the additional columns with SQL code

Comment: you can create an initial script with the existing sql from the database and use it with liquibase or flyway

Comment: i think this solution can help me right now  , i will try this method , thank you for replying